# Remove specific line from file C++

Tags: c++

I've been struggling all day with this problem. I can't make my program to delete an specific line of my file. I have a list of names in my file and I would like to delete one of them, I don't know what I'm missing.

EDIT: Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

string fname;
string keyword;
int phone_num;
ifstream myfile;
ofstream phone;

void Add()
{
  ofstream phone("number.txt", ios::app);
  cout << "Enter Name: ";
  cin >> fname;
  cout << "Enter Phone Number: ";
  cin >> phone_num;

  if (phone.is_open())
  {
    phone << fname << endl;
    phone << phone_num << endl;
    cout << "Contact saved successfully!" << endl;
  }
  phone.close();
}

void All()
{
  ifstream myfile("number.txt", ios::in);
  while(myfile >> fname >> phone_num)
  {
    for(auto name : fname)
    {
      cout << name;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

void Delete()
{
  ifstream myfile("number.txt", ios::in);

  cout << "Enter Name to delete : ";
  cin >> keyword;

  while(getline(myfile, keyword))
  {
    fname.replace(fname.find(keyword),keyword.length(),"");
  }
}
```

Comment: Once you read a line into a `string` variable, it has no connection to the file; in particular, changing the string will not affect the file.  Worse, making change to a string that sounds like it contains the *name* of a file (but was never initialized) will not affect the file.

Comment: What exactly do you think `getline(myfile, keyword)` is doing? What do you expect to happen given that you never initialized `fname` before calling `fname.replace(...);`?

Comment: I posted my whole code, I don't know what I'm missing. Can you check again, please ? Thanks @ScottHunter

Comment: If you want to modify a file the easiest way to do that is read the file in line-by-line (which you are doing) *and then write the lines out again to a different file* (which you are not currently doing) except for the line you want removed.  Then you can delete the original file and rename the new one to the original file’s filename.